# ReferenceError: window is not defined in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-owl-carousel plugins in my projects. when run my project displayed **ReferenceError: window is not defined** error showing, what I am missing could you please solve this issue.

```
F:\react\test\testsite> npm run ssr

> testsite@0.1.0 ssr
> node server/index.js

F:\react\test\testsite\node_modules\react-owl-carousel\umd\OwlCarousel.js:1795
    })(window.Zepto || window.jQuery, window, document);
       ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at F:\react\test\testsite\node_modules\react-owl-carousel\umd\OwlCarousel.js:1795:8
    at F:\react\test\testsite\node_modules\react-owl-carousel\umd\OwlCarousel.js:2:85
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\react\znap\znapcash\node_modules\react-owl-carousel\umd\OwlCarousel.js:5:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Module._compile (F:\react\znap\znapcash\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (F:\react\test\testsite\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
PS F:\react\test\testsite>
```

Comment: you want `globalThis`, not `window`. The DOM `window` object only exists in engines that implement the DOM APIs, which Node does not. [globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis), however, is always available. But if this is a third party library, you should probably read its documentation for how to successfully bundle it in, since you will definitely not be the first person to ever try that.

Comment: Shall i change window to globalThis? is right. this url not working https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis()